# Функция добавления элемента в динамическую структуру

Tags: c++, структуры, динамическое-программирование

При написании программы - база данных магазина компьютерной техники возникла такого рода ошибка:

В функцию передается массив структур, где должен добавиться новый элемент, алгоритм работы функции расписал ниже. После вызова функции массив структур отображается некорректно (выводит мусор), а при повторном вызове функции ошибка при выполнении.

**Структура:**

```
struct computers
 { 
char group[12]; 
        char name[54];
        char brand[10];
        double price;
};
```

Сама функция:
*table - таблица элементов
&quantity - кол-во элементов в таблице (изменяется в функции на +1)

```
...
void addProduct(computers *table, int &quantity)
{
    computers *tempTable = new computers[quantity]; //Создаем временную таблицу
    for (short i = 0; i < quantity; i++) //Переносим все из основной таблицы в временную
        tempTable[i] = table[i]; 
    delete[] table; //Удаляем основную таблицу
    quantity++;
    table = new computers[quantity]; //Выделяем память для основной таблицы, но уже на +1 эл-м больше 
    for (short i = 0; i < quantity - 1; i++)
        table[i] = tempTable[i]; //Переносим все из временной таблицы в основную
    delete[] tempTable; //Удаляем временную таблицу
//Заполняем новый элемент:
    strcpy(table[quantity - 1].group, "Мыши");
    strcpy(table[quantity - 1].brand, "Asus");
    strcpy(table[quantity - 1].name, "Компьютерная мышь Asus");
    table[quantity - 1].price = 199;
}
...
```

**В main():**

```
...
int *mouseQ = new int(5);
computers *mouse = new computers[*mouseQ];

//Массив элементов уже заполнен данными

do
{
addProduct(mouse, *mouseQ);

//Вывод таблицы на экран

system("pause");
} while(1);
...
```

Подскажите, в чем проблема. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Оставляя в стороне вопрос об оптимальности представленного решения (пересоздание и копирование всего массива при добавлении каждого элемента), проблема кроется в том, что в функции

```
void addProduct(computers *table, int &quantity)
```

указатель table передается по значению, а не по ссылке. Поэтому, когда внутри этой функции его значение меняется (в результате убийства старого массива и создания нового), во внешнюю переменную mouse этот новый адрес не попадает (как вы, вероятно, ожидаете). А остается там старый адрес, который уже освобожден. Отсюда и мусор в первый раз. Ну а при последующих вызовах, вы повторно освобождаете уже освобожденную память. Поэтому все валится. А вообще, для решения задач с меняющими размер массивами есть такое библиотечное средство, как std::vector. Очень рекомендую освоить и использовать - код станет сильно проще и быстрее (по крайней мере, в сравнении с вашим решением). Как и вообще стандартную библиотеку.

Для починки же вашего решения достаточно поменять заголовок так:

```
void addProduct(computers* &table, int &quantity)
```

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ!
В данный момент учусь в КА ШАГ, и до std::vector еще не дошли, поэтому пишу программы пользуясь тем - что знаю)